# Passing many variables to a class (swing components)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am writing a GUI with many components (panel, buttons, text areas ~ 50 items). I also have a lot of **classes** (custom Action Listeners and some threads). It's not viable to keep them all in the same .java file so they can all access the GUI components (~1500 lines total).

Almost all **classes** need information from or access to components, usually  to about 5-6. The question is: is there a better way to handle them other than passing them one by one? Is there any harm in doing it? (other than the gross looking unclear code)

One idea is to make a class and stash all the components there and pass on the whole class. Most **classes** through only need 10% of them (usually different ones), so I don't know if it's worth it. Is there a price to pay for passing so many unused references?

I don't have much of programming background and it's pretty much my first java program (and maybe the last one). But I need to do a good job of it in a relatively small amount of time.

Comment: It sounds as if you have one or more god-classes in there. Get a decent book on refactoring and go through it, you won't regret doing this.

Comment: [Such as](http://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html)

Comment: *"Almost all classes need information from or access to components, usually to about 5-6."*  It sounds like there should be data model(s) that can be passed to whatever components might need them.